# how to install python pip on python 2.7

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, easy-install, pypi

2 days ago i had [a problem with pypm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928728/activepython-pypm-is-not-working) and couldn't fix it so i uninstalled activepython, and I wanna install pip which suppose to be an alternative to pypm

I've been looking around for 6h and still stuck lol, I have installed setuptools, now what and how to run pip? from the command line? from python command line?...if i want to install django using i used to open pypm and write pypm install django, but i can't use pypm anymore, and the documentation is so confusing and no blogger has made his own easy to follow tutorial!!

i'm so confused and don't know what to do? I downloaded distribute but didn't install it, all i have is a bunch of files inside the folder maybe it's the source! I'm so confused lol, all i know is that setuptools is installed but don't how to run it lol, i'm on xp pro...

Comment: what i usually do is installing activepython (it's still a great python distribution, it sets paths for you and a few other useful things), then using pypm to install pip. Then after that i only use pip. Never had any problem this way.

Comment: pip is in distribute, not in setuptools. You could try pip's installer script here: https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py

Comment: @MatToufoutu

i love activepython sir but pypm is not working at all, it won't install anything take a look

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928728/activepython-pypm-is-not-working

Comment: @Thomas K  when i run get-pip.py i have the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\get-pip.py", line 32, in <module>
    sources = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(base64.decodestring(sources)))
NameError: name 'sources' is not defined

Comment: @MatToufoutu - activepython already _includes_ pip

Comment: @Elie: I think you haven't saved it right, because that's not line 32. You need to save the whole file, including the big block at the top that looks like nonsense.

Comment: @Thomas K: excuse me sir,silly mistake lol the actual error is this 

http://pastebin.com/BebbtAQV

it's so big, so i had to paste it on pastebin

Comment: @Thomas K: there's something wrong with my python, i just can't import modules, I don't think it's a bug coz i have deleted activepython and everything, I think there's an error

Comment: You might just want to try uninstalling Python completely and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2 days ago i had a problem with pypm and couldn't fix it

I've responded to this problem [in the ActiveState forum](http://community.activestate.com/node/6965#comment-17751).

> so i uninstalled activepython, and I wanna install pip
>   [...]
>   I have installed setuptools,
>   [...]
>   I downloaded distribute

There is no reason why have to uninstall ActivePython. Even if `pypm` doesn't work, ActivePython **already includes** `pip` (among setuptools/distribute/easy_install).

> pip [is] supposed to be an alternative to pypm

pip and pypm complement each other; the former allows you to compile the packages yourself (slow and unreliable process especially on Windowds), while the later allows you to install pre-built binary packages. See [How is PyPM related to pip and easy_install?](http://code.activestate.com/help/faq/#how-is-pypm-related-to-pip-and-easy_install)

**tl;dr** - [let's fix your pypm problem](http://community.activestate.com/node/6965#comment-17751), and you'll be happy for it.

Comment: thanks sir, just one thing python -m pypm.client.command -f install distribute didn't work so i have to rename "%APPDATA\Python, i have some questions:  where to find "%APPDATA\Python on xp? what should i rename it? anything? and finally lets assume that didn't am i able to install activepython on virtualbox (ubuntu)?

Comment: because that seems to be a good solution in case i can't fix it on xp

Comment: @Elie - click the "Start" menu and click "Run" ... then type `%APPDATA%` and press ENTER. Rename that `Python` folder into something else (eg: `Python.old`). And, yes, you can install ActivePython on Ubuntu by downloading the Linux package (32-bit or 64-bit depending on your platform); extract and run the ./install.sh script on terminal.

Comment: thanks sir so much it worked and everything is perfect but i have 2 questions: could you see this http://tinyurl.com/454re6p  pypm works perfectly but i see these lines, should i ignore them or what?

and if i have a similar error in the future, should i follow the same procedure to fix it?

Comment: @Elie - This is a different error, but belongs to your PyGTK install. You are safe to ignore it (pypm will continue to function normally), but it is best to report this to the PyGTK mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

```
easy_install pip
pip install django
pip install whatever you like
```

all in terminal

Comment: these command didn't work coz they're not recognized...did i miss to install something?

Comment: but you can start python, wit typing python in terminal? if you isntalled setuptool scorrectly you should be able to use easy_install

Comment: to run python from terminal i have to type cd C:\python27 and then type python ...because i previously have installed activepython so if i type python without specifying the directory it say: (activepython based software) python 2.7.2

Comment: did you uninstall active python with the active python uninstaller listed under system-software

Comment: yes i did sir,anyway it matter if you uninstall it with the uninstaller or with the add and remove in cpanel, because it will always uninstall with the same way i tried that

Comment: alright then look where the new python is and check if you find easy_install anywhere cause thats what you need in order to install packages